# Spring Boot and @ComponentScan between two jars

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have 2 projects.
One is a DAL project that does CRUD operations on a neo4j DB using spring neo4j APIs . This project is packaged as a jar and included in project #2.
Project #2 Is a Spring restful services project that uses spring boot to package and create an executable jar that runes on an embedded tomcat server.

When trying to run my executable jar that Spring boot has created for me I keep getting this exception.
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Based off of my reading if I am using @ComponentScan I can give the annotation directories to look in. So I give it the base dir for my services project. And I give it the base dir for my included DAL.jar but still no luck here is what the annotation looks like.

Extracted from comments:

Component scan declaration

```
@ComponentScan({"com.foo.dal.*","com.foo.notification.*"})
```

Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pushCommandsController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.teradata.dal.example.PushRepository com.teradata.notification.rest.controller.PushCommandsController.repository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.teradata.dal.example.PushRepository] found for dependency:
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

UPDATE:

based off of @chrylis answer:
Made change to @ComponenetScan

```
@ComponentScan({"com.teradata.notification","com.teradata.dal"})
```

running in to:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.MessageSourceAutoConfiguration' is defined
```

MORE DETAIL ON THE DAL PROJECT AND THE SERVICE PROJECT:

DAL PROJECT:

[image: DAL project structure]

---

[image: DAL classes]

---

[image: DAL classes]

---

[image: DAL classes]

---

[image: DAL classes]

---

Services Project:

[image: Service project structure]

---

[image: Service classes]

---

[image: Service classes]

---

[image: Service classes]

Comment: Sorry forgot the annotation that I am using

Comment: @ComponentScan({"com.foo.dal.*","com.foo.notification.*"})

Comment: Don't use "thanks" and please attach code sample. As well as exception thrown.

Comment: I included the relevant part of the stack trace but here is the full print out.

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pushCommandsController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.teradata.dal.example.PushRepository com.teradata.notification.rest.controller.PushCommandsController.repository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.teradata.dal.example.PushRepository] found for dependency:

Comment: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Comment: com.teradata.notification.rest.controller.PushCommandsController is not component scanned? But it looks like this class is not even a class of your library.

Comment: sinisa229 yes sorry in my example I used foo and not the package name and did't change it in the stack trace. some what new to posting on stack.

Comment: More detail is good, but always post text like the contents of your images as text. Images are difficult to read and can't be searched or copied for testing.

Answer (score 19):

The argument to `@ComponentScan` is a package name, and those strings aren't valid packages. Drop the `.*` from them; Spring scans subpackages automatically.

Comment: You are right but that won't help. As @sinisa229 stated the missing autowiring dependency is not in the scanned packages, even if the names would be fixed...

Comment: @DirkLachowski It looks like it actually is; the OP posted obfuscated package names but didn't do it completely, and I figured as much.

Comment: Dirk Lachowski I used the package name foo in my @ComponenetScan as an example and forgot to change it in the stack trace.

Comment: Made change : '@ComponentScan({"com.teradata.notification","com.teradata.dal"})'

Comment: running in to 'java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.MessageSourceAutoConfiguration' is defined'

Comment: @MuhiMasoud So basically component scanning is now working but you are running in another error (triggered by spring boot). Looks as if you have to ask another question.

Comment: @DirkLachowski I'm going to add more detail on this Question first and then ask a new one. Just can't post screen shots bc I don't have 10pts.

Comment: @MuhiMasoud You do now.

Comment: You should accept the answer to this question (otherwise your reputation is only going to get worse).

Answer (score 2):

Had this same issue for a short while, then `@EntityScan` did the trick for me, just as adviced here - [Spring Boot w/ JPA: move @Entity to different package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23366226/spring-boot-w-jpa-move-entity-to-different-package).

Hope that helps