# Spring Boot w/ JPA: move @Entity to different package

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot

I'm having trouble with my first steps using Spring-Boot with JPA. I've started with a pretty minimalistic [example from Git](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-jpa.git) using Gradle.

Now simply moving `Customer` to another package, let's say to `hello2` results in an exception `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class hello2.Customer`. I tried to add

`@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses= {Customer.class}) // AND OR
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses= {Customer.class})`

to `Application`, but without success.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Location of entities in Spring Boot can be configured using [`@EntityScan`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/orm/jpa/EntityScan.html).

By default, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` enables entity scanning in the package where it's placed (if it's not a default package).

Comment: I am using this

@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(value="org.package.spike.entities")

where org.package.spike.entities is the package that contains my entity classes

still i get the same problem

Comment: This is a couple years later, but i am also getting this same thing.  Tried every possible config i can think of but am still getting "not a managed type" put @EnableAutoConfiguration and @EntityScan("my package") in my repository configuration and still get this error.

Answer (score 35):

You must locate entities and repositories pakages by using

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "your.repositories.pakage")

@EntityScan(basePackages = "your.entities.pakage")
```

Comment: I was missing @EntityScan, my entities and my repos are in different packages. You can alternatively use @EntityScan(basePackageClasses = AClassInPackageWhereAllEntitiesAre.class)
Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

this is what worked for me :

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages ={ "package1","package2"})
@EntityScan(basePackages ={ "package3","package4"})
```

Answer (score 1):

Giving same package location (i.e base package) for below annotation worked for me :-

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"org.ashu.java.*"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages ={ "org.ashu.java.*"})    
@EntityScan(basePackages ={ "org.ashu.java.*"})
```